# Why EXISTS() always returns true?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Here is my query (used in a `TRIGGER`):

```
update user_details
set views_profile = views_profile + 1
where user_id = new.user_id and not exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM views_profile vp
    WHERE vp.user_id = new.user_id and vp.viewer_id = new.viewer_id
)
```

The `TRIGGER`:

[image]

As you can see, my query is an `UPDATE` statement and the problem is, it never happens. According to some tests, the problem is related to `EXISTS`. When I remove it, that `UPDATE` happens.

Anyway, why `EXISTS` is true all the time? Even when there isn't any row in `views_profile` table?

Comment: You need a sub-query condition referencing the outer query's table, i.e. a user_details column.

Comment: i would recommend you to share the data with such query. try any www.dbfiddle.uk or www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: You are using a `TRIGGER`? Can you show the trigger?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Yes, It's a trigger https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxOgx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `TRIGGER` with `AFTER INSERT` so the new line is available on the `UPDATE` (and can be found on the `EXISTS`). You can change the time to `BEFORE`.